# Entity Framework 6 - Retrieve null instead of default if query contains no rows

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

**Entity Foo:**

`public int Foo { get; set; }`

**EF-Query:**

```
int? barX = FOOs.GetQuery().Where(f => f.x == x).Select(f => f.bar).SingleOrDefault();
```

Returns default value 0 for integer if there are no rows where `f.x == x` but I want to return `null`.

How to achieve this?

*0 is no clear indicator wether the result was empty or the columns value is really 0!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing the projection in the query you could pull back the full entity and project after:

```
var foo = FOOs.GetQuery().Where(f => f.x == x).SingleOrDefault();
int? barX = foo != null ? (int?)foo.bar : null;
```

If you are worried about fetching the whole entity then you could return an anonymous type instead of the full thing:

```
var foo = FOOs.GetQuery().Where(f => f.x == x).Select(new { bar = f.bar }).SingleOrDefault();
int? barX = foo != null ? (int?)foo.bar : null;
```

Thanks to @Flater since I did not know this was possible (just cast it in the projection):

```
int? barX = FOOs.GetQuery().Where(f => f.x == x).Select(f => (int?)f.bar).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: this is a valid workaround but i dont want to fetch whole entity if possible

Comment: From OP's original snippet, should `.Select(f => (int?) f.bar).SingleOrDefault()` not fix the problem? Seems a more concise approach than adding an additional evaluation to the code.

Comment: @Flater Well sure, if you want simple code. =) I edited the answer again with your suggestion, but feel free to post an answer yourself and I will remove the edit.

Comment: Thank you @Flater. Still I think this is a big issue in EF!

Comment: How is this a big issue in EF? Your field is a non-nullable int. You expect EF to convert it to a nullable int for you? How does that make sense. That would be far more broken.

Comment: @djmj: To be fair, int simply cannot be null. It's not that EF doesn't want to return an null, it's because the language does not support `null` for value types.

Comment: To be more fair, if the result set is empty there is no `int` that could not be null.

Comment: @djmj Single = give me the only item there is. Default = give me the default value if there are no items. default(int) = 0. default(int?) = null. It's not an Entity Framework thing it is a C# thing.